# google +1 button - tell it to ignore hash parameters?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

How do I pass options to the the google +1 button to use the base url, and ignore the hash parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#target-url) specifies three different methods of specifying the URL to get +1'd.

> 1. The button's href attribute
> 2. The page's `<link rel="canonical" ... />` tag
> 3. The URL provided by document.location.href (not recommended)

The easiest way is to write `<g:plusone href="..."></g:plusone>`.